# Help Understanding This Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, normal-distribution, bayesian, gaussian

I am working through a [paper here](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/%7Esnelson/SPGP_up.pdf) and trying to understand all of the linear algebra involved, but I get stuck going from equations 5-6 to equation 7. I will skip the bold matrix notation because everything is a matrix/vector

#### Equation 5

$$
p(y|X, \bar{X}, \bar{f}) = \mathcal{N}(y|K_{NM}K_{M}^{-1}\bar{f}, \Lambda + \sigma^2I)
$$

#### Equation 6

$$
p(\bar{f}|\bar{X}) = \mathcal{N}(\bar{f}|0, K_{M})
$$

#### Equation 7

The paper says "we find the posterior distribution over pseudo targets $\bar{f}$ using Bayes' rule on (5) and (6)."

$$
p(\bar{f}|\mathcal{D}, \bar{X}) = \mathcal{N}(\bar{f}|K_MQ^{-1}_MK_{MN}(\Lambda + \sigma^2I)^{-1}y, K_MQ_M^{-1}K_M)
$$

where

$$
Q_M = K_M + K_{MN}(\Lambda + \sigma^2I)^{-1}K_{MN}
$$

By saying that they used Bayes' rule, they are saying that they are doing the following...

$$
p(\bar{f}|\mathcal{D}, \bar{X}) = \frac{p(y|X, \bar{X}, \bar{f})p(\bar{f}|\bar{X})}{p(y)}
$$

But I do not see where they can get the denominator from as it is not given. I tried multiplying the likelihood by the prior in the numerator using [these Gaussian identities](https://cs.nyu.edu/%7Eroweis/notes/gaussid.pdf), but I go something totally different, not even close to the definition of $p(\bar{f}|\mathcal{D}, \bar{X})$. How can you combine the equations 5 and 6 with Bayes' rule to get equation 7?

**EDIT: WIP to get details final derivation correct**

#### Point 1

I am now very close to getting the full thing, but there is one part that is eluding me, which is probably something trivial. For one, the proportions have different x values, so I think there needs to be some subscript to set the variables apart, like so...

$$ \exp(a(x_1-b)^2) \exp(cx_2^2) \propto \exp((a+c)x_2^2 - 2abx_1).$$

which would mean that $1 \rightarrow 2$ could be represented as...

$$
\begin{align} 
 & \propto \exp(-\frac{1}{2} (y - L \mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}(y - L \mu))\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\mu^T K^{-1} \mu) \\
&\propto \exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\underbrace{-2\mu^T L^T \Sigma^{-1}y + \mu^T(\Sigma^{-1}+K^{-1})\mu}_\text{Terms that do not include $\mu$ are factorized away})) \\
\end{align}
$$

if it is the case that...

$$
\begin{aligned}
a &= \Sigma^{-1} \\
b &= \mu^TL^T \\
c &= K^{-1} \\
x_1 &= y \\
x_2 &= \mu \\ 
\end{aligned}
$$

But I do not see how we would end up with $L^T\Sigma^{-1}L + K^{-1}$ inside of the parentheses at the end.

#### Point 2

I think the final line of the derivation is missing an inverse at the end, is it correct?

$$ 
\propto \exp(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\mu - (L^T\Sigma^{-1}L+K^{-1})^{-1} L^T \Sigma^{-1} y\right)^T (L^T\Sigma^{-1}L+K^{-1})^{\color{red}{-1}} \left(\mu - (L^T\Sigma^{-1}L+K^{-1})^{-1} L^T\Sigma^{-1} y\right)).
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Preamble

I shall use the common Bayesian statistics trick used in figuring out the posteriors - work with PDF kernels and figure out the normalization constants later. I will also make an intensive use of the *proportionality* arithmetic, $\propto$, which simplifies the derivations.

The main logic of $\propto$ relation is expressed as:

$$ C_1\exp(C_2 + h(x)) \propto C_3\exp(C_4 + h(x)) \propto \exp(h(x))$$

for any constants $C_i$ and $h(\cdot)$ is some function of $x$.

Obviously $f(x) \propto h(x)$ implies $h(x) \propto f(x)$.

The following relations are relatively not obvious but will be useful below:

$$ \exp(a(x-b)^2) \propto \exp(ax^2 - 2ab x) \propto \exp(ax(x-2b)),$$
$$ \exp(a(x-b)^2) \exp(cx^2) \propto \exp((a+c)x^2 - 2ab x).$$

### Tedious algebra

So, we have normally distributed data $y|\mu \sim \mathcal{N}(L \mu, \Sigma), \mu\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and normally distributed mean parameter $\mu \sim \mathcal{N}(0, K)$. The posterior density of $\mu$ is proportional to the product of PDF kernels of the two:

\begin{align} 
  \overline{p}(\mu|y) \quad & \propto \exp(-\frac{1}{2} (y - L \mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}(y - L \mu))\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\mu^T K^{-1} \mu) \\
&\propto \exp(-\frac{1}{2}(\underbrace{-2\mu^T L^T \Sigma^{-1}y + \mu^T(L^T \Sigma^{-1}L+K^{-1})\mu}_\text{Terms that do not include $\mu$ are factorized away})) \\
&\propto \exp(-\frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\mu^T(L^T\Sigma^{-1}L+K^{-1})}_\text{Factorized inside $\exp$} \left(-2 (L^T\Sigma^{-1}L+K^{-1})^{-1} L^T\Sigma^{-1} y + \mu\right))\\
&\propto \exp(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\mu - (L^T\Sigma^{-1}L+K^{-1})^{-1} L^T \Sigma^{-1} y\right)^T (L^T\Sigma^{-1}L+K^{-1}) \left(\mu - (L^T\Sigma^{-1}L+K^{-1})^{-1} L^T\Sigma^{-1} y\right)).
\end{align}

Careful examination of the last line reveals the PDF kernel of a normal rv

$$\mu|y \sim \mathcal{N}((L^T\Sigma^{-1}L+K^{-1})^{-1} L^T\Sigma^{-1} y, (L^T\Sigma^{-1}L+K^{-1})^{-1}). $$

Using the [Woodbury identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) one can rewrite the posterior covariance with an eye on simplifying it in the context of the paper:

$$ 
(L^T\Sigma^{-1}L+K^{-1})^{-1} = K - K L^T(\Sigma + L K L^T)^{-1} L K
$$

In the context of the paper,

\begin{align}
\mu &= \overline{f}, \\  \Sigma &= \Lambda + \sigma^2 I, \\  K &= K_M,\\
L &= K_{NM}K_M^{-1}, \\ KL^T &= K_{MN}, \\  L K L^T &= K_{NM} K_M^{-1} K_{MN},
\end{align}

and the posterior covariance matrix equals

\begin{align} 
&K_M - K_{MN} (\Lambda + \sigma^2I + K_{NM} K_M^{-1} K_{MN} )^{-1} K_{NM} \\
=& K_M (K_M^{-1} - K_M^{-1} K_{MN} (\Lambda + \sigma^2I + K_{NM} K_M^{-1} K_{MN} )^{-1} K_{NM} K_M^{-1} ) K_M\\
=& K_M (K_M + K_{MN} (\Lambda + \sigma^2 I)^{-1}K_{NM})^{-1} K_M \\
= & K_M Q_M^{-1}K_M. 
\end{align}

(Woodbury identity is used again to get the third line.)

The mean of the posterior is obtained in a similar fashion.

Comment: I haven't had time to go through everything in your answer in detail yet, but the posterior covariance seems to be incorrect because it is listed as $K_MQ^{-1}K_m$. $Q$ matches  what is in the parentheses in the third line of your last equation except the sign is different in your answer, the paper puts $Q$ as $K_M + K_{MN}(\Lambda + \sigma^2 I)K_{NM}$. Is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: Yes in the last line, it is of course $K_M Q_M^{-1}K_M$, just check the previous line. And be sure to go through everything in detail, because the manipulations are quite standard, very common in the literature, this will serve you well.

Comment: Thanks, are you aware of any source where I can learn common patterns like this instead of trying to piece them together when I see them in papers?

Comment: There are not so many of these patterns, actually. This one is the most common. 
Try scrolling through [these](https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~xian/coursBC.pdf) notes. They are by [professor Christian P.Robert](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/7224/xian) who is an active user of stats.stackexchange.com. The stats site is very rich as well, everything ML, statistics, probability related - they know the answer.

Comment: yeah I probably should have asked this on the stats site. Thanks

Comment: I had a chance to look over things carefully. I cannot follow step 1->2, 3->4, and 4->5 in the generic derivation at the top of your answer, but I can follow the rest of the answer. Is it possible to elaborate a little bit more on these steps?

Comment: @deltaskelta Please check the updated answer, I added a little preamble to help you make sense of steps 1-2, 3-4 and 4-5

Comment: Wow so I understand the factorization in step three and I get the step from 3->4 from the top row of $\propto$'s. I must be very dense because I still do not see the move from 1->2. I can see that it has to do with the bottom row of $\propto$'s but I cannot get there on paper.

Comment: I fixed a typo in the bottom row of my $\propto$'s.

Comment: I am now just missing one detail which is probably something trivial. I have edited my question to show where I ended up in the step from 1->2. Can you see what I am missing? Thanks for all your help so far, I would have never been able to figure out all these tricks on my own.